# Data structure to perform fast GPS lookups?

Tags: java, python, data-structures, gps, gis

I have a text file (UTF-8, ~50K lines) with city names and GPS coordinates. Example lines:

```
San Pedro    locality   -3367   -5968   Argentina       Buenos Aires    San Pedro
Talagante    locality   -3366   -7093   Chile   Metropolitana   Talagante
Peñaflor     locality   -3362   -7092   Chile   Metropolitana   Talagante
```

The third and fourth columns are the GPS coordinates of the cities in the last columns.

Given a GPS coordinate, I need to find the closet city. I need to do this hundreds of millions of times. What are some tools that can help me with this task? Java/Python solutions would be ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [KD tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). I found a link to a [python implementation](http://code.google.com/p/python-kdtree/) for it here, but I am not python developer, never tried it. The KD tree will support for square root complexity of finding the nearest point in a plane, which is maybe the best complexity you can get. You can afford making probably about a million queries a second.

**EDIT:** Actually your question made me make a bit more thorough research. Probably you will find useful what is described as possible approaches on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). What you are interested in is providing optimal solution for many queries of nearest neighbour.

Answer (score 2):

I would store these records in a SQLite database. There is a project called [SpatiaLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpatiaLite) that adds spatial queries and types on top of SQLite. This lets you ask the database things like "give all items within 20 meters of x".

If you don't want to use a database you could use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). There are several implementations in Python. A quadtree divides a rectangular space into 4 parts, and then subdivides each part into 4 more parts. Searching is very efficient.

Comment: SpatiaLite may be a great way to do this, but I'm not familiar with SQLite and will probably be fine with a KDTree.

Answer (score 1):

For geometric queries like you are asking(closest point) KD Tree is excellent data structure. Besides not very tough to implement. I have a Java implementation. Not sure how efficient it would be for you. It was my assignment. `Point2D` and other utility classes are implemented [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/index.php). You can view their source code there. `RectHV` is another utility class needed. It is written by me.

```
public class RectHV {
    private final double xmin, ymin;   // minimum x- and y-coordinates
    private final double xmax, ymax;   // maximum x- and y-coordinates

    // construct the axis-aligned rectangle [xmin, xmax] x [ymin, ymax]
    public RectHV(double xmin, double ymin, double xmax, double ymax) {
        if (xmax < xmin || ymax < ymin) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid rectangle");
        }
        this.xmin = xmin;
        this.ymin = ymin;
        this.xmax = xmax;
        this.ymax = ymax;
    }

    // accessor methods for 4 coordinates
    public double xmin() { return xmin; }
    public double ymin() { return ymin; }
    public double xmax() { return xmax; }
    public double ymax() { return ymax; }

    // width and height of rectangle
    public double width()  { return xmax - xmin; }
    public double height() { return ymax - ymin; }

    // does this axis-aligned rectangle intersect that one?
    public boolean intersects(RectHV that) {
        return this.xmax >= that.xmin && this.ymax >= that.ymin
            && that.xmax >= this.xmin && that.ymax >= this.ymin;
    }

    // draw this axis-aligned rectangle
    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.line(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymin);
        StdDraw.line(xmax, ymin, xmax, ymax);
        StdDraw.line(xmax, ymax, xmin, ymax);
        StdDraw.line(xmin, ymax, xmin, ymin);
    }

    // distance from p to closest point on this axis-aligned rectangle
    public double distanceTo(Point2D p) {
        return Math.sqrt(this.distanceSquaredTo(p));
    }

    // distance squared from p to closest point on this axis-aligned rectangle
    public double distanceSquaredTo(Point2D p) {
        double dx = 0.0, dy = 0.0;
        if      (p.x() < xmin) dx = p.x() - xmin;
        else if (p.x() > xmax) dx = p.x() - xmax;
        if      (p.y() < ymin) dy = p.y() - ymin;
        else if (p.y() > ymax) dy = p.y() - ymax;
        return dx*dx + dy*dy;
    }

    // does this axis-aligned rectangle contain p?
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
        return (p.x() >= xmin) && (p.x() <= xmax)
            && (p.y() >= ymin) && (p.y() <= ymax);
    }

    // are the two axis-aligned rectangles equal?
    public boolean equals(Object y) {
        if (y == this) return true;
        if (y == null) return false;
        if (y.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
        RectHV that = (RectHV) y;
        if (this.xmin != that.xmin) return false;
        if (this.ymin != that.ymin) return false;
        if (this.xmax != that.xmax) return false;
        if (this.ymax != that.ymax) return false;
        return true;
    }

    // return a string representation of this axis-aligned rectangle
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + xmin + ", " + xmax + "] x [" + ymin + ", " + ymax + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is KD tree:

```
public class KdTree {

    private static class Node {
        private Point2D p;      // the point
        private RectHV rect;    // the axis-aligned rectangle corresponding to this node
        private Node lb;        // the left/bottom subtree
        private Node rt;        // the right/top subtree

        Node() {
            p = null;
            rect = null;
            lb = null;
            rt = null;
        }
    }

    private Node tree;
    private Point2D nearestPoint, infinitePoint;
    private int sz;
    private double nearestDist;


    // construct an empty set of points
    public KdTree() {
        tree = new Node();
        sz = 0;
        infinitePoint = new Point2D(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    }



    // is the set empty?
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (sz == 0);
    }



    // number of points in the set
    public int size() {
        return sz;
    }



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // private function for inserting any element //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void privateInsert( Node nd, Point2D p, int lv, double xmin, double ymin, double xmax, double ymax) {
        if(nd.p == null) {
          nd.p = p;
          nd.rect = new RectHV(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
          nd.lb = new Node();
          nd.rt = new Node();
          sz = sz + 1;
        }
        else if( lv % 2 == 0 ) {
            double X = nd.p.x();
            double x = p.x();
            if( x <= X ) {
                xmax = X;
                privateInsert(nd.lb, p, lv+1, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
            }
            else {
                xmin = X;
                privateInsert(nd.rt, p, lv+1, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
            }
        }
        else {
            double Y = nd.p.y();
            double y = p.y();
            if( y <= Y ) {
                ymax = Y;
                privateInsert(nd.lb, p, lv+1, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
            }
            else {
                ymin = Y;
                privateInsert(nd.rt, p, lv+1, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax);
            }
        }
    }



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // private function for searching any element //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private Node privateSearch( Node nd, Point2D p, int lv ) {
        if( nd.p == null ) return nd;
        else if( p.equals( nd.p ) == true ) return nd;
        if(lv % 2 == 0) {
            double X = nd.p.x();
            double x = p.x();
            if( x <= X ) {
                return privateSearch( nd.lb, p, lv+1 );
            }
            else {
                return privateSearch( nd.rt, p, lv+1);
            }
        }
        else {
            double Y = nd.p.y();
            double y = p.y();
            if( y <= Y ) {
                return privateSearch(nd.lb, p, lv+1);
            }
            else {
                return privateSearch(nd.rt, p, lv+1);
            }
        }
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // private function for drawing all the points //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void privateDraw (Node nd) {
        if(nd.p == null) return;
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(.01);
        double x = nd.p.x();
        double y = nd.p.y();
        StdDraw.point( x, y );
        privateDraw( nd.lb );
        privateDraw( nd.rt );
    }



    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // private function for range searching //
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    private void privateRange(Node nd, RectHV rect, Queue<Point2D> que){
        if(nd.p == null) return;
        if( rect.contains( nd.p ) == true ) que.enqueue( nd.p );
        if( nd.rect.intersects(rect) == true ) {
            privateRange(nd.lb, rect, que);
            privateRange(nd.rt, rect, que);
            return;
        }
        else return;
    }




    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // private function for searching nearest neighbour //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void privateNearest( Node nd, Point2D p ) {
        if(nd.p == null) return;
        double d = p.distanceSquaredTo(nd.p);
        if(d < nearestDist) {
            nearestDist = d;
            nearestPoint = nd.p;
        }
        if(nd.lb.p != null && ( nd.lb.rect.distanceSquaredTo(p) < nearestDist) ) privateNearest(nd.lb, p);
        if(nd.rt.p != null && ( nd.rt.rect.distanceSquaredTo(p) < nearestDist) ) privateNearest(nd.rt, p);
    }



    // add the point p to the set (if it is not already in the set)
    public void insert(Point2D p) {
        if( contains( p ) == true ) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            privateInsert(tree, p, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00);
        }
    }



    // does the set contain the point p?
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
        Node nd = privateSearch(tree, p, 0);
        if(nd.p == null) return false;
        else return true;
    }



    // draw all of the points to standard draw
    public void draw() {
        privateDraw(tree);
    }



    // all points in the set that are inside the rectangle
    public Iterable<Point2D> range( RectHV rect ) {
        Queue<Point2D> que = new Queue<Point2D>();
        privateRange(tree, rect, que);
        return que;
    }



    // a nearest neighbor in the set to p; null if set is empty
    public Point2D nearest(Point2D p) {
        nearestPoint = infinitePoint;
        nearestDist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        privateNearest(tree, p);
        return nearestPoint;
        //return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use your post to list explicitly the KD tree complexity: it is `O(log N)` average complexity with O(sqrt(N)) worst case time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoHash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) is another choice for you, which is quite each to implement, efficient as fast.