# Geospatial lookup

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, lookup

I'm developing a algorithm and data structures to handle lookup by euclidean distance on a large quantities of 2-dimentional points.

I've tried researching this on google scholar but found nothing yet (probably because I don't know what this problem is usually called in the literature).

These are the two approaches I've considered:

Approach 1:
Create a bidimentional grid with buckets. Insert points into buckets, keeping a reference of each point's bucket. 
On lookup of point P with distance D, get its bucket B and all the buckets where any of the corners of its grid-square have (distance to B)  < D.
Finally, enumerate the points in all those buckets and calculate distance to P.

Approach 2:
Create two lists, each with all the point ordered by one of the coordinates (x,y). On lookup of point P with distance D, perform binary search to find two points in each of the list in order to find the rectangular region where points have their Chebyshev distance to P < D. 
    Finally, calculate euclidean distance of all those points to P

I'm guessing the state-of-the-art algorithms will be vastly superior to this, though? Any ideas on this are appreciated

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this question, but this link may be of help - it explains how MongoDB's geospatial indexing is implemented. http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/06/08/mongo-in-flatland/

Comment: Are you asking about [2D rendezvous](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TwoDimensionalRendezvous) or [2D range query](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TwoDimensionalRangeQuery)?

Comment: @DavidCary None, it seems, though it's more similar to 2d range query. The problem can be summarized as "find all points whose euclidean distance to point P is less than D"

Comment: @Rich That's interesting. It looks similar to the approach 1 I mentioned, in that points are bucketed in a grid

Comment: I had a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902264/data-structure-to-perform-fast-gps-lookups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tips to help you:

- Take a look at [KDTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), it is a k-dimensional tree (2d in your case) which is one of the best ways to look for nearest-neighbors.
- Perhaps you could benefit from a [Spatial Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_database_systems), specifically developed to deal with Geospatial Data;
- You could use any of the above with your desired distance function. Depending on your application, you want map distance, great circle distance, constant slope distance, constant bearing distance, etc. Your distance function should be known by you. I use to apply great circle (haversine) distance to deal with google-maps-like maps and tracks.

In case you want a Python implementation, there is `scipy.spatial` ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html)). From this module, the function `query_ball_point((px, py), radius)` seems to be what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In particular, a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (another word for a 2d KDTree) would be the default solution, especially if you use a Euclidean distance function on rectangular coordinates (i.e. if you ignore the curvature of the Earth's surface).

Comment: @ErikP. I imagine a Quadtree to be a regular subdivision (dividing square cells in half to obtain half-sized, smaller square cells), while a KDtree not necessarily divides cells in equal-sized sub-cells. Instead, in the KDtree, the subcell dimensions would depend on point distribution inside the cell. Is that correct?

Comment: I tend to think of (ir)regularity of the subdivision as an (important!) implementation choice within KDTrees (or quadtrees, for that matter), but I'm starting to believe that you're correct and that my usage of the terms is non-standard. At any rate, in this case I think both regular and irregular subdivision would work, in principle; it would probably depend on the point distribution which approach would work best.

Comment: @ErikP. I have seen quadtrees being used to subdivide space, which might or might not contain data, such as the map space of webmaps. Now if you subdivide a pointcloud by itself, the KDtree approach uses irregular (optimized) subdivision. Of course, if you have to refer the points' location inside the quadtree'd space, that is another task. And all this stuff is amazing and fun!

Comment: K-dTrees and Quadtrees look very interesting and may offer a great advantage to the grid approach by only subdividing when needed. Now I just need to implement the algorithm to find all the points in a circle, but it seems fairly simple. Thanks, heltonbiker and Erik P.!

Comment: @goncalopp If you decide to use `scipy.spatial`, you can use the function `query_ball_point((x,y), radius)`. Unfortunately I don't know about implementations in other languages, but for sure there must be some.

Comment: I actually need to implement this in Scala, but since the [pure-python source is available](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/kdtree.py) and python is **extremely** readable, this will make the job much easier, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this (and others that might be around): http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~mlewis/CSCI1321-S11/Code/Eclipse/src/adt/KDTree.scala